# Dynamically update a table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page where I send an ajax request to a server. There is a table on the page which displays some data. The server returns a json object which is a list of objects and it doesn't contain any layout for the page.

I want to update only table **rows** by returned json. How can I do this without using third-party libraries and only using jquery? I just want a rough idea and example.

Comment: *"... without using third-party libraries and only using jquery"* Uh... that'll be tricky.

Comment: can be achieved with native JavaScript -- can you offer an example of the JSON data format?

Comment: ...but to answer, you select a row, and update its cells with the received data. There's your rough answer. Now give it a try, and if you get stuck on something specific, ask about that.

Comment: @nathan, let's say, it's: `Good: price, weight, length, color`.

Comment: @thesystem, it's very rough. Would you mind giving me an example?

Comment: @AlanDert: Please provide what you've tried. Give some concrete information like the actual data structure, and the table structure. Explain in detail what you do and don't know, and you'll be able to get a much more useful answer. Right now your question is way too broad.

Comment: ...in other words, if you want someone to write a tutorial for you, this isn't the right place. There are countless tutorials available online. You need to read through some of that information, and try things for yourself first.

Comment: @AlanDert check this link http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ and please show some effort in your question, do some little codes :D

Comment: define `update`, provide some sample html and some sample data. If all you are needing to do is add rows, is quite easy. Otherwise to update existing rows have to be able to see what identifiers exist to make th matches

Comment: also should look at plugins that have integrated server side updates

Comment: I think @Alan knows that `$(aTable).html(rows)` (for example) can parse rows inside a table. I guess, he is looking for an approach on managing the fields. Not asking for a production-ready application.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is the [**demo fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/edMGf/). (simple version)
***NEW:*** See the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/kBQdS/) (advanced version).

Let's say you have this JSON data retrieved:

```js
var jsonData = [
    { field1: 'value a1', field2: 'value a2', field3: 'value a3', field4: 'value a4' },
    { field1: 'value b1', field2: 'value b2', field3: 'value b3', field4: 'value b4' },
    { field1: 'value c1', field2: 'value c2', field3: 'value c3', field4: 'value c4' }
];
```

And you have this table:

```html
<table id="data-table">
    <tr><td>There are no items...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, you need a method that can parse the values in a customisable order and presence. For example, if you can pass a field array to the parser function; you can set the order of the fields and leave out a field or two if you want to:

```
loadTable('data-table', ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'], jsonData);
```

Notice that `field4` is not parsed.

The `loadTable` function loops through the items of the returned array and create a `<tr>` with each field value inside a `<td>`. Here is the simple function:

```js
function loadTable(tableId, fields, data) {
    //$('#' + tableId).empty(); //not really necessary
    var rows = '';
    $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var row = '<tr>';
        $.each(fields, function(index, field) {
            row += '<td>' + item[field+''] + '</td>';
        });
        rows += row + '<tr>';
    });
    $('#' + tableId).html(rows);
}
```

### UPDATE:

Added support for:

- Table headers
- Default text (for empty list)
- Appending lists
- Clearing the table
- etc...

You can now simply include an empty table and the `dynamicTable` will take care of the rest:

```
<table id="data-table"></table>
```

Call the `dynamicTable.config()` method to configure the table:

```js
var dt = dynamicTable.config('data-table', //id of the table
                             ['field2', 'field1', 'field3'], //field names
                             ['header 1', 'header 2', 'header 3'], //set to null for field names to be used as header names instead of custom headers
                             'There are no items to list...'); //default text for no items
```

Then call `dt.load(data);` to load new data (removes the previous list if there is one),
OR call `dt.load(data, true);` to append the new data at the end of the previous list.

Calling `dt.clear();` method will clear the whole list.

[**Updated fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/onury/kBQdS/).

Comment: if `data-table` already has headers, how do add/re-render rows for it without loosing its headers? `$('#' + tableId).html(rows);` re-writes the whole table including its headers.

Comment: For that, you can use `<thead>` and `<tbody>` tags inside the table and modify the jQuery selector accordingly. e.g.: `$('#' + tableId + ' tbody').html(rows);` See the advanced version in the updated answer.

Comment: any idea why this code outputs the 'field' values out of order? this is the output... "value a2 value a1 value a3".

Comment: @Ryan_S  Because of the order the table was initialized with: `['field2', 'field1', 'field3'], //field names` I believe this was done to show you that the order matters.

Comment: A great solution - however i did notice that a redundant row gets created for every row with data created - so if you try and alternate formatting using css (e.g. tr:nth-child(even)) on even numbered rows this fails as the hidden row absorbs the change.

Comment: Managed to find the problem - the closing tag for <tr> does not have a "/".  Line 19 of your js reads: row += '<tr>'; it should read row += '</tr>';

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your JSON objects.

```
$.each(JSON_Object, function(key, value) {
    // Write your code here
});
```

Then you can simply append your table with data.

```
$('#yourTableName tr:last').after('<tr><td>John</td><td>$500</td></tr>');
```

Since you specifically mentioned that you don't need 3rd party libraries, you can do something like above. However if you need dataset with all the features, you can consider some plugin like http://datatables.net/.

Comment: if I don't want to append (I need appending as well) but replace the current rows with the new ones, how do I do that?

Comment: If you want to show all new rows. First empty the table. and then display new rows.

Answer (score 0):

If the table in question is associated to an oData service (e.g. as is standard in Fiori) with an item reference in the table XML such as `items="{/ReportSet}"` then a request to update the table with a filter will automatically update the table items i.e. in JS:

```
eTable.bindItems(sPathR,template,null,this.instanceFilter);
```

- sPathR is the entity set e.g. `/ReportSet` in the above
- `template` should be the item template in the table
- `this.instanceFilter` is the defined filter set prior to the call