# create links in dynamic table fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im new to Javascript and im struggling with this question for a while.

I have a dynamic jquery table and my goal is to hyperlink one row of that table (the row data) to a .php page to make some queries.

My objective is something like this:

for example, in the table

```
   data       info         money          name          ID
 20161001   ...           34            test         1010
 20161002   ....          20            dddd          111
 20161003    ...           12            ....        .....
```

users could press 20161001 or 20161002 and this would link to a detailed table with all the info of this day

My first problem is to reach the object inside the array of data.

Every time i try to reach data i got something like : [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

The only way i could reach them was from:

```
 JSON.stringify(data[i])
```

i made a for statement but this return all the info from table and i just need the data from the row: Data.

for my dynamic table i get the headers from :

```
    var keys=[];

              for (var key in data[0]) {
                keys.push(key);
                  }
```

I also try to combine this 2 ways to reach the info but no success.

My ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
                      type: 'post',
                      url: "data.php",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: $(this).serialize(),

                      success: function(data) {
                           console.log(data);


                              $('#btn-load').click(function(e) {



                                var keys=[];

                                for (var key in data[0]) {
                                    keys.push(key);
                                }


                                dt = dynamicTable.config('data-table', //id of the table
                                                         keys, //field names
                                                         null, //set to null for field names to be used as header names instead of custom headers
                                                         'no data...');

                                    dt.load(data);
                        });
```

(Dynamic table with code of this page:
[Dynamically update a table using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949210/dynamically-update-a-table-using-javascript#comment53182637_14949543))

I need to reach this info, link him and pass the value into a php page.

I don't know if this method is the more appropriate so if someone can give me some lights i would appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to pass into your link?? Data? or Is?

Comment: i Will pass the Data as a String to use on querie...for example, all the datas will link to a .php page , and that php page will receive the value of data to a querie.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to pass the first column value of the row into your php function you can just try this.

Bind a click event to your table `tr`  using event delegation (as you said it's a. Dynamic table) and extract the first `td` value on click.

```
$("#yourTableId").on("click","tr",function(){
   var data = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
   alert(data); //test
});
```

Comment: Gonna try this when i reach home, but makes sense ;) . thanks

Comment: Do you know one function that can be inserted inside the one you gave me to link to a .php page ?' I have try the "fnRowCallback" but with no sucess

Comment: The above script must work. I assume you are using DataTables plugin.. so when ever you page , sort etc there are new tr elements drawn into table.. Also to get the data from a dataTable row there is a different syntax.

Comment: the above code will give me the data of the <td> as string and that works 5 stars, my problem now is to link that td to a php page. For example, the table is generated and have datas, i click on a data field and redirect me to a php page ( and send the data to use in querie)

Comment: Ok, finally done. Thanks for the big help Reddy , i could finalize the data this way :   dt.load(data);
                                            $("#data-table").on("click","tr",function(){
                                             
                                               var data2  = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
                                              
                                               window.open("teste.php?data2="+data2,'_blank','toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=400,width=400,left=200, top=300');

Comment: Also you can use `window.location` to reload the same tab with new page.. right now you are opening a new window

Answer (score -1):

```
                          $("#data-table").on("click","tr",function(){

                                           var data2  = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();


                                           window.open("teste.php?data2="+data2,'_blank','toolbar=0,location=no,menubar=0,height=400,width=400,left=200, top=300');  
                                           console.log (data2);
```

Thans for the help Reddy . This solve the problem, i pass the data trough the Window.open  ;)